# Connect to Exchange using Ksoap2 for android

Tags: android, email, exchange-server, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am trying to use ksoap2 to connect to an exchange web server to create an email app in android. So far I have very little to go on since Microsoft doesn't give a straight forward explanation of how to use the autodiscover soap methods. So far this is all I have

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        String userpass = username+password;
        NTCredentials cred = new NTCredentials(userpass);
```

I am using Android API 21 since it still has the NTCredentials methods. My question then is how do I connect to an exchange server. And then is there anything else I need to do to view email or send email. My app already can show the inbox for a imap or pop3 mail client so can I just connect to the exchange server using ksoap then just use the already defined methods for imap and pop3 to do everything else?

Comment: i havnt done this myself before but i would assume its like calling a normal web service with ksoap2. There is a list of methods here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb409286(v=EXCHG.140).aspx

Comment: I have seen that list before. This is why I mentioned that microsoft has rather muddy documentation. Because if you look at this list it doesn't really have any method that deal with connections.

Comment: I should also say I realize it's like calling a normal web service, with the exception that you have to first make sure that NTcredentials are set. But what method do I give these credentials to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above I have not done this before, but i have used ksoap2 a bit, so i would try something like this:

```
String NAMESPACE = "http://www.namespace.com/";
String METHOD_NAME = "MethodName";
String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE+METHOD_NAME;
String URL = "https://www.namespace.com/services/Service.asmx";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
// Set all input params   
request.addProperty("property", "value");   
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
// Enable the below property if consuming .Net service
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
try 
{
    List<HeaderProperty> headerList = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();
    //I would use this for authentication
    headerList.add(new HeaderProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encode((username+":"+password).getBytes())));

    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope, headerList);
    SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

This is [Basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side).